# Managing argument input value usage inside an R function

Tags: r, function

My function `foo` is meant to compute a variable called `d` using one of its arguments: `s`, `t`, or `f`.

For example, if a user uses `foo(n = 30:35, s = 1:2, t = 3:5, f = 7)` I want `foo` to first compute `d` using `t`, then `f`, and then `s`. Thus, in the output, I expect **6** `d`s (i.e., **2 from `t`, 1 from `f`, and 2 from `s`**).

I want the the first 2 `n`s be for `t`, the next `n` be for `f`, and the remaining `n`s be for `s`. Is there a way I can mange `n`s inside the function this way?

```
foo <- function(n, s = NULL, t = NULL, f = NULL){

d1 <- if(!is.null(t)) t + n else NULL
d2 <- if(!is.null(f)) f^2 + n else NULL

m <- if(!is.null(s)) s/2 + n else NULL
r <- if(!is.null(m)) m + 1 else NULL

d3 <- if(!is.null(m)) m + r else NULL

data.frame(d = c(d1, d2, d3))
}

 # Example of use:
 foo(n = 30:35, s = 1:2, t = 3:5, f = 7)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can loop through the elements of 't', 'f', 's', add (`+`) with 'n' and get the output in a `list`

```
foo <- function(n, s = NULL, t = NULL, f = NULL){

      dts <-  if(!is.null(t)) sapply(t, `+`, n) else NULL
      dfs <- if(!is.null(f)) sapply(f^2, `+`,  n) else NULL

      ms <- if(!is.null(s)) sapply(s/2, `+`,  n) else NULL
      rs <- if(!is.null(ms)) ms + 1 else NULL

      dss <- if(!is.null(ms)) ms + rs else NULL

      list(t_out =dts, f_out = dfs, s_out = dss)
      }

 # Example of use:
foo(n = 30:35, s = 1:2, t = 3:5, f = 7)
```

Comment: Thanks, my real function is not going to use `+` I just used a simple example. But I think I can't achieve what I have in mind. Anyways, thank you so much.

Comment: @rnorouzian  If it is a complicated funciton, use anonymous function call `sapply(t, function(x) yourfunction(x, n))`

Comment: Arun, is [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56209856/deleting-an-element-from-all-embedded-lists-in-a-list-in-r) difficult to achieve?