# deleting an element from all embedded lists in a list in R

Tags: r, list, function, loops, lapply

I have a list (`g`) of lists as shown below. To *delete* element `k` from one of the embedded lists (ex. 1st list), I can do: `g[[1]]$k <- NULL`.

But when I try to *delete* element `k` from all embedded lists, my `lapply` code fails? Is there a Base R fix?

```
g <- list(b1 = list(data.frame(a = 1:3), k = 4:6), b2 = list(data.frame(a = 8:9), k = 7:9))

lapply(1:length(g), function(i) g[[i]]$k <- NULL) ## FAILS to delete `k` from all embedded lists
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R is a functional language and as such copies of arguments are passed rather than pointers to them. Functions are not supposed to make modifications on the "originals" of the arguments. So you should not assume that modifications to values accessed inside function will be "visible" outside that function's environment *unless* there is an assignment back to the original name (or to an alternate name such as is done here):

```
> g2 <- lapply(g, function(i){ i$k <- NULL; i})
> g2
$b1
$b1[[1]]
  a
1 1
2 2
3 3


$b2
$b2[[1]]
  a
1 8
2 9
```

Note also: the need to return the modified element after the "k" value is nulled out. Seemed more direct to pass the actual elements rather than using an index. There is an implicit exception to the rule of "no modifying of arguments" allowed to the `<-` and `<<-` functions.

Answer (score 3):

You can do

```
lapply(g, function(x) x[names(x) != "k"])
#$b1
#$b1[[1]]
#  a
#1 1
#2 2
#3 3


#$b2
#$b2[[1]]
#  a
#1 8
#2 9
```

Or alternatively

```
lapply(g, function(x) { x[names(x) == "k"] <- NULL; x })
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option with `discard`

```
library(purrr)
map(g, ~ discard(.x, names(.x) == "k"))
#$b1
#$b1[[1]]
#  a
#1 1
#2 2
#3 3


#$b2
#$b2[[1]]
#  a
#1 8
#2 9
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @42-:

```
lapply(g, '[[<-', 'k', NULL)

# $b1
# $b1[[1]]
#   a
# 1 1
# 2 2
# 3 3

# $b2
# $b2[[1]]
#   a
# 1 8
# 2 9
```